# Android Dropbox Sync SDK Authentication View Not Being Dismissed

Tags: android, android-webview, dropbox, dropbox-api

I noticed this strange issue when testing the user authentication in Dropbox Sync SDK. The main problem is that after a successful authentication (entered username and password in the webview, and allowing the application access to a certain folder) the authentication appears to be dismissed (as it should be), but to my surprise it wasn't. After hitting the back button, I was taken back to the authentication dialog, instead of exiting my application, as if my view was pushed from the authentication dialog, instead of really dismissing the dialog (webview) after the authentication.

I tried modifying the values in the Dropbox activity in my manifest but with no luck:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask" >
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="db-xxxxxx" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing still on the screen isn't AuthActivity, it's the browser which was launched by AuthActivity.  It returns to the app via a redirect, which doesn't actually close the browser.  If the official Dropbox app is installed, you won't see this behavior, since it will be used instead of the browser for the authorization flow.

Comment: Hope that we see that fixed. This could be quite confusing for users with no Dropbox app installed on their devices. Thanks